# Replacing fancyhdr with scrpage2

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, scrpage2

I'm trying to reduce the number of packages I'm loading in my documents and I read on the KOMA documentation (and elsewhere) that it can define page styles better than `fancyhdr`. But each time I try to set up `scrpage2` I get weird results, such as with the wrong section titles or positioning of elements. How can I rewrite my `fancyhdr` layout to `scrpage2`?

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\scshape \mytitle{}}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\scshape \thechapter. \leftmark{}}}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage{}}
}

\fancypagestyle{preface}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\scshape \leftmark{}}}}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\scshape \mytitle{}}}}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage{}}
}
```

The `preface` style is used for the pages before Chapter 1; other pages just use the default `fancy` style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a `scrpage2` solution that should at least come close to what you want. Some remarks:

- No head- and footrules is the default setting of `scrpage2`.
- Disabling uppercase letters in the header is done by the package option `nouppercase`.
- The optional arguments of `\lohead`, `\rehead` and `\cfoot` control the settings for the `scrplain` pagestyle (which replaces `plain`).
- The heading font is controlled by the `\headfont` macro.

I didn't emulate your separate `preface` pagestyle (which differs only slightly from your `fancy` style). Instead, I redefined `\chaptermarkformat` (which is able to differentiate between numbered and unnumbered chapters).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lohead[]{(mytitle)}% Placeholder for \mytitle
\rehead[]{\leftmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\itshape\scshape}% Will equal \scshape for most fonts
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% Unnumbered chapters

\blinddocument

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}% Numbered chapters, sections, and subsections

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Comment: With `scrbook` generally you do not need `nouppercase`, because the KOMA-Script classes do not use `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: `scrpage2` is obsolete. You can simply replace it by `scrlayer-scrpage`. You should then also replace `\clearscrheadfoot` by `\clearpairofpagestyles` and you can remove `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`. Instead of re-defining `\headfont` you should use `\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{…}`.