# English minitoc entry within a Greek utf8 document

Tags: table-of-contents, unicode, babel, greek, minitoc

In a document set up as shown in the question [Greek pdf bookmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41614/8272), the interesting bits are:

```
\documentclass[greek,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc} % define LGR and T1 encodings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % standard UTF-8 input encoding
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
```

The [minitoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package is used to present mini-ToCs on a per-chapter basis.

```
\usepackage[k-loose]{minitoc} % Mini-ToCs with loose line spacing
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{} % for empty title
\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off} % turn off rules before and after the minitoc's
\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off} % turn off page numbering in minitoc's
```

All but one section titles are Greek. The only English section, named *Thumb index* and correctly (?) defined in English using `\selectlanguage{english}`, appears with Greek letters in the mini-ToC as *Τηυμβ-ινδεξ*.

**Note** the section title appears correctly in the (normal) Table of Contents!

How should be [minitoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) instructed to respect the language setting?

Comment: Please, try building a minimal example.

Comment: Right, working on it...

Comment: What is LGRx encoding? I couldn't find it on CTAN.

Comment: @Stephan: You can find the LGRx files here: http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/

Comment: I am trying to produce a MWE from a LyX document. I have some problems with minitoc under pure LaTeX. Stephan's proposition (1st Answer, below) works fine. I'll try to provide a LaTeX-MWE later...

Comment: Working example posted as an answer below. Not a minimal one, rather a demo of a unicode(d) document with mixed greek, english, pdf bookmarks and minitoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many aspects in the example document that need to be straightened:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,greek,BCOR=20mm, footnoterule,
  lists=totoc, index=totoc, captions=bottombeside, open=any,
  iso-8859-7,latin9,utf8]{scrbook}

\usepackage[LGRx,T1,LGR]{fontenc} % define LGR and T1 encodings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % standard UTF-8 input encoding
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=20mm,bmargin=30mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=30mm}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[k-loose]{minitoc} % loose line spaced minitoc
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{} % for empty title
\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off} % turn off rules before and after the minitoc's
\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off} % turn off page numbering in minitoc's

\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,breaklinks=true,
  pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=page,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark} % pdf bookmarks

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Αναφορά...},
 pdfauthor={Νίκος Αλεξανδρής},
 pdfsubject={Υλοποίηση...},
 pdfkeywords={minitoc, greek, english, babel, unicode, LaTeX},
 linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=red, pdfstartview={FitH}, 
 hyperfootnotes=false, unicode=true}

\usepackage{kerkis} % fonts
\usepackage[final,expansion=true,protrusion=true]{microtype} % kerning/margin

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % Textclass specific LaTeX commands

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.2} % define lightgray

%%% Important!
\addto\extrasenglish{\def\encodingdefault{T1}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
\dominitoc


\title{\foreignlanguage{english}{An english minitoc-entry in an LGRX encoded document}}
\subtitle{\foreignlanguage{english}{A (not exactly Minimal) Working Example!}}

\author{του Νίκου Αλεξανδρή%
\thanks{\foreignlanguage{english}{\protect\href{mailto:nik@}{nik@}}}}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Σχεδιασμός~και υλοποίηση}
\minitoc

\section{Δομή εγγράφου\label{sec:a}}

\section{Δομή σελίδας\label{sec:b}}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\begin{itemize}

\item \foreignlanguage{greek}{(ύψος κειμένου)}
$textheight:\,\unit[438]{pt}*\unit[0.3515]{mm}=\unit[153.957]{mm}$

\item \foreignlanguage{greek}{(πλάτος κειμένου)}
$textwidth:\,\unit[746]{pt}*\unit[0.3515]{mm}=\unit[262.219]{mm}$

\item
$\nicefrac{textwidth}{2}:\,\nicefrac{\unit[746]{pt}*\unit[0.3515]{mm}}{2}=\unit[131.1095]{mm}$
\end{itemize}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\subsection{Κεφαλίδες~και Υποσέλιδες~σημειώςεις}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\begin{itemize}
\item \sout{use }\emph{\sout{scrpage2}}\sout{ instead of }\emph{\sout{fancyheader}} (see also:
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/replacing-fancyhdr-with-scrpage2}%
  {tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/replacing-fancyhdr-with-scrpage2})
\end{itemize}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\subsection{Δομή πλάγιων σελίδων}

(=\foreignlanguage{english}{landscape})
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\begin{itemize}
\item balance up with respect to page width!
\item in each landscape page: 2x 48\% column width(ed) boxes
\item inside column-boxes: vertically stacked, and centered, 2x photos sized
49\% of text height
\end{itemize}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\section{\texorpdfstring{\foreignlanguage{english}{Thumb index}}{Thumb
index}}
\label{Section: Thumb - Index}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\begin{itemize}
\item using \code{chapterthumbs.sty}
by Markus Kohm (e.g., among other places also to be found at
\href{file:http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty}%
  {http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty})
\end{itemize}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

Explicit usage of `\selectlanguage` is seldom needed. The definition you give of `\textgreek` is useless, as Greek is the default language. It's conversely needed a similar trick for the English text.

Inputting `σ` and `ς` directly is obviously possible.

Comment: It works, superb :D

Comment: What exactly instructs the command `\addto\extrasenglish{\def\encodingdefault{T1}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}`?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris It's just the correspondent instruction to your `\greektext` so that switching to English will surely change the font encoding.

Answer (score 5):

How did you define the english section?

The following

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{\selectlanguage{english}Thumb index}{Thumb index}}
```

seems to work here.

Comment: I only used `\selectlanguage{english}%
\section{Thumb-index}`. Your code works fine though!

Comment: Just to be very clear: in the above comment, "my" simple `\section` definition, does not cause any problems in the section title itself, nor in the pdf bookmarks. Just in the minitoc.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris This is understandable. For the document itself, changing language before `\section` is enough. The bookmark is handeled by the unicode option. But the toc entry gets scrambled by inputenc because in LGR encoding, the greek characters are in the same place as usually the latin ones and the language selection is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

A (not exactly Minimal, though successful) Working Example after following Stephan Lehmke's suggestion:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,greek,BCOR=20mm, footnoterule, lists=totoc, index=totoc, captions=bottombeside, open=any, iso-8859-7,latin9,utf8,english,greem]{scrbook}

\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc} % define LGR and T1 encodings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % standard UTF-8 input encoding
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=20mm,bmargin=30mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=30mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{units}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=page,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Αναφορά...},
 pdfauthor={Νίκος Αλεξανδρής},
 pdfsubject={Υλοποίηση...},
 pdfkeywords={minitoc, greek, english, babel, unicode, LaTeX},
 linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=red, pdfstartview={FitH}, hyperfootnotes=false, unicode=true}

\makeatletter


\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % Textclass specific LaTeX commands

\usepackage{bookmark} % pdf bookmarks
\usepackage{breakurl} % breakurl's
\usepackage{kerkis} % fonts
\usepackage[final,expansion=true,protrusion=true]{microtype} % kerning/margin

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.2} % define lightgray

\usepackage[k-loose]{minitoc} % loose line spaced minitoc
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{} % for empty title
\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off} % turn off rules before and after the minitoc's
\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off} % turn off page numbering in minitoc's


\begin{document}


\title{\selectlanguage{english}An english minitoc-entry in an LGRX encoded document}
\subtitle{\selectlanguage{english}A (not exactly Minimal) Working Example!}

\author{του Νίκου Αλεξανδρή%
\thanks{\selectlanguage{english}%
\protect\href{mailto:nik@}{nik@}\selectlanguage{greek}
%
}}

\maketitle

\selectlanguage{english}%
\dominitoc
\mtcprepare
\tableofcontents{}

\selectlanguage{greek}%
\chapter{Σχεδια\textsigmaμό\textvarsigma~και υλοποίη\textsigmaη}
\minitoc

\section{Δομή εγγράφου\label{sec:=000394=0003BF=0003BC=0003AE-=0003B5=0003B3=0003B3=0003C1=0003AC=0003C6=0003BF=0003C5}}

\section{Δομή \textsigmaελίδα\textvarsigma\label{sec:=000394=0003BF=0003BC=0003AE-=0003C3=0003B5=0003BB=0003AF=0003B4=0003B1=0003C2}}
\begin{itemize}
\item (ύψο\textgreek{c} κειμένου) \foreignlanguage{english}{$textheight:\,\unit[438]{pt}*\unit[0.3515]{mm}=\unit[153.957]{mm}$}
\item (πλάτο\textgreek{c} κειμένου) \foreignlanguage{english}{$textwidth:\,\unit[746]{pt}*\unit[0.3515]{mm}=\unit[262.219]{mm}$}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\item $\nicefrac{textwidth}{2}:\,\nicefrac{\unit[746]{pt}*\unit[0.3515]{mm}}{2}=\unit[131.1095]{mm}$
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Κεφαλίδε\textvarsigma~και Υπο\textsigmaέλιδε\textvarsigma~\textsigmaημειώ\textgreek{svει}\textvarsigma}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\begin{itemize}
\item \sout{use }\emph{\sout{scrpage2}}\sout{ instead of }\emph{\sout{fancyheader}}
\foreignlanguage{greek}{(}see also:\foreignlanguage{greek}{ }\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/replacing-fancyhdr-with-scrpage2}{tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11220/replacing-fancyhdr-with-scrpage2}\foreignlanguage{greek}{)}
\end{itemize}
\selectlanguage{greek}%

\subsection{Δομή πλάγιων \textsigmaελίδων}

(=\foreignlanguage{english}{landscape})
\selectlanguage{english}%
\begin{itemize}
\item balance up with respect to page width!
\item in each landscape page: 2x 48\% column width(ed) boxes
\item inside column-boxes: vertically stacked, and centered, 2x photos sized
49\% of text height
\end{itemize}
\selectlanguage{greek}%

\section{\texorpdfstring{\selectlanguage{english}Thumb index}{Thumb index}}\foreignlanguage{english}{\label{Section: Thumb - Index}}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\begin{itemize}
\item using \code{chapterthumbs.sty}
by Markus Kohm (e.g., among other places also to be found at \href{file:http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty}{http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty})
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Edit freely if you think the above code does not need to be that "complicated" as an answer to the initial question.

Comment: Why are you using `\textsigma` and `\textvarsigma`? If I input the characters `σ` and `ς` directly, I get what's expected.

Comment: Please, add this to your original question.

Comment: @egreg Do you get the characters `σ` and `ς` correctly displayed in the pdf bookmarks as well? I don't expect so (after all I've read and been advised). If otherwise, it would save a lot of handwork :-)

Comment: Look at the bookmark for section 1.2 with my code. I see "∆οµή σελίδας"

Comment: @egreg About adding this in the original question: no objections. But, the code above came only after Stephan Lehmke's answer (above) and further homework. Isn't it actually another answer?